# Google Cloud Scheduler different frequency based on weekdays (2 lines of cron)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a job I want to run every 15 mins on Monday to Saturday but every 5 mins on Sunday, I tried to input the following to Cloud Scheduler but it's saying invalid format:

```
*/15 * * * 1-6, */5 * * * 0
```

Are 2 lines of cron not allowed? Do I need to create 2 identical jobs and set a different schedules for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a line from GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules#defining_the_job_schedule):

> You can define a schedule so that your job runs multiple times a day, or runs on specific days and months. A schedule is described using the unix-cron string format (`* * * * *`), which is a set of five values in a line, indicating when the job should be executed.

Meaning, each job can only have 1 schedule. The answer to your last question is *yes*. If you have multiple schedules, then each of them must be configured as separate jobs.

Answer (score 0):

i think they need to be on 2 different lines and not coma separated:

```
*/15 * * * 1-6
*/5 * * * 7
```

Comment: doesnt let me do 2 lines, ended up creating 2 jobs